# Retrofit and SimpleXML for unknown root element?

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, simple-framework

We are currently working on setting up Retrofit for an XML API - unfortunately **each request can return a response with one of two different root elements**.

Normally, each response looks like this (of course, the actual elements contained within the `<response>` tag vary with each request):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <SomeInfo>Some Info</SomeInfo>
    <MoreInfo>More Info</MoreInfo>
</response>
```

And each error looks like this (the structure here is the same for each response):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
    <code>125002</code>
    <message></message>
</error>
```

Now, the only way we've found so far to get this work in a somewhat generic way is the following:

```java
public interface Api {

    @GET("/api/sessionToken")
    Observable<ResponseBody> requestSessionToken();

    @GET("/api/pinStatus")
    Observable<ResponseBody> requestPinStatus();
}

public class RestClient {

    public RestClient() {
        // ...
        mApiService = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }

    public Observable<PinStatusResponse> requestPinStatus() {
        return mApiService.requestPinStatus()
                .flatMap(foo(PinStatusResponse.class, PinStatusResponseData.class));
    }

    public Observable<SessionTokenResponse> requestSessionToken() {
        return mApiService.requestSessionToken()
                .flatMap(foo(SessionTokenResponse.class, SessionTokenResponseData.class));
    }

    private final <O extends MyResponse, I> Func1<ResponseBody, Observable<T>> foo(final Class<O> outerCls, final Class<I> innerCls) {
        return new Func1<ResponseBody, Observable<O>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<O> call(ResponseBody responseBody) {
                try {
                    final String xmlString = responseBody.string();

                    final XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
                    parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    parser.setInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))), null);
                    parser.nextTag();

                    final String rootTag = parser.getName();

                    final Serializer serializer = new Persister();

                    if (TextUtils.equals(rootTag, "error")) {
                        final MyError myError = serializer.read(MyError.class, xmlString);
                        return Observable.just((O) outerCls.getConstructor(MyError.class, innerCls).newInstance(myError, null));
                    } else if (TextUtils.equals(rootTag, "response")) {
                        final I data = serializer.read(innerCls, xmlString);
                        return Observable.just((T) outerCls.getConstructor(MyError.class, innerCls).newInstance(null, data));
                    }
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    return Observable.error(e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return Observable.error(e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return Observable.error(e);
                }
                return Observable.error(new Exception("Should not be reached..."));
            }
        };
    }
​}
```

Where the Response classes look like this:

```java
public abstract class MyResponse<T> {
    public final MyError error;
    public final T data;

    protected MyResponse(MyError error, T data) {
        this.error = error;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and:

```java
public final class PinStatusResponse extends MyResponse<PinStatusResponseData> {
    public PinStatusResponse(MyError error, PinStatusResponseData data) {
        super(error, data);
    }
}
```

And all the `*Data` classes correspond directly to the (non-error) XML responses.

Now, my question is: **Is there really no easier way to solve this?** (And if so, is this a sign of bad API design?).

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `@ElementUnion` annotation is for. You could probably work it out using pure Retrofit+SimpleXML API by using an annotated object like so:

```
@Root
public class ResponseBody {

    public interface IApiResponse {
    }

    @Root
    public static class ValidResponse implements IApiResponse {
        @Element(name="SomeInfo") String someInfo;
        @Element(name="MoreInfo") String moreInfo;
    }

    @Root
    public static class ErrorResponse implements IApiResponse {
        @Element(name="code") int code;
        @Element(name="message") String message;
    }

    @ElementUnion({
        @Element(name="response", type=ValidResponse.class),
        @Element(name="error", type=ErrorResponse.class)
    })
    IApiResponse apiResponse;
}
```

* Concrete structure of 'ValidResponse' and 'ErrorReponse' would have to be altered according to the real XML structure you have. You might also wish to consider adding `'strict=false'` in their `@Root`.

As for your 'Api' interface, it would then have to look like this (note I've slipped in the usage of Retrofit's Call class):

```
public interface Api {

    @GET("/api/sessionToken")
    Call<ResponseBody> requestSessionToken();

    @GET("/api/pinStatus")
    Call<ResponseBody> requestPinStatus();
}
```

And finally, the call itself (to e.g. requestPinStatus()) should be worked out according to this skeletal implementation:

```
Call<ResponseBody> result = mApiService.requestPinStatus();
result.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        // ...

        if (response.body().apiResponse instanceof ValidResponse) {
            // ...
        } else if (response.body().apiResponse instanceof ErrorResponse) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

For more info on `ElementUnion` and Simple-XML annotations, refer to [this guide](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#union).

Comment: OK, thanks - I'll try that and then report back here!